# Excel If cell is blank show nothing else carry out this IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have the following formula

```
=IF(N37="Y",5,-5)
```

At the moment it shows -5.00 if the cell N37 is blank however I have it to display nothing until the cell contains N or Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming -5 is supposed to be when you have `N`:

```
=IF(N37="Y",5,IF(N37="N",-5,""))
```

If Y, then 5.

If Not Y, then, IF N, -5.

If Not Y and Not N, "" (blank string)

Answering your comment, you need to use a slightly different formula if using numbers:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(P37)),NOT(ISBLANK(O37)),P37<=O37/2),"Y",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(P37)),NOT(ISBLANK(O37)),P37>=O37/2),"N",""))
```

As blank cells will be treated as zero

Comment: Thank you very much ! I think you were first by a few seconds so I'll give it to you :)

Comment: Can you help with another one...I have used your code above but it is still displaying Y even when the 2 fields are blank...

`=IF(P37<=O37/2,"Y",IF(P37>=O37/2,"N",""))`

Comment: @PhilNind That's slightly different because you're comparing them as numbers, and a blank cell = 0 (Hence, 0 <= 0/2, Y). So, now things get messy ;). Try `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(P37)),NOT(ISBLANK(O37)),P37<=O37/2),"Y",IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(P37)),NOT(ISBLANK(O37)),P37>=O37/2),"N",""))` - basically checking the fields aren't blank as well as doing the comparison.

Comment: It is throwing up an error possibly too many brackets

Comment: @PhilNind Think it's something to do with the formatting in comments, try the amended answer.

Comment: Still no dice :/ I appreciate your help massively

Comment: @PhilNind Really? I just copied and pasted directly from the answer and it worked fine (The one in my comment doesn't though...)

Comment: Yep my bad got it working now :) thank you so much